# How to transform LINQ filter expression to SQL Query?

Tags: sql, linq, odata

I'm wondering how I can transform a FilterExpression in LINQ into a SQL clause.

```
{it => (IIF((it.DatasetTitle == null), null, Convert("Ref".Contains(it.DatasetTitle))) == Convert(True))}
```

Are there any convenient ways of changing the above expression to a SQL clause?

Comment: what are you looking for ? Just the Sql translation of this clause ?

Comment: I'm looking for ways of translating LINQ expression into a SQL clause.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, you wouldn't do this directly.  The underlying object which implements the IQueryable that you're performing the LINQ operation on would handle this work.  Since you tagged OData, I presume you're using WCF Data Services.  In your context object, you can declare your DbSet typed properties.  DbSet implements IQueryable, and will do this for you.

Comment: I used WCF Data Service Toolkit to implement a custom data service provider. To use the library I have to make a GetAll(ODataQueryOperation oDataQueryOperation) method for each repository. The method gets data and filter them based on the parameter passed by users. And in the oDataQueryOperation, I can find a FilterExpression object that has a set of OData System Queries. I wnant to extract the expression to build a WHERE clause.

Comment: Are you not using Entity Framework, nHibernate, or other ORM under WCF DS?

Comment: I'm using WCF DS Toolkit with ODataLib 5.4.